# Complete list of App Store review rejection reasons

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I am iOS Developer. I have seen and had very bad experiences with App Store approval process.

We have developed an app according to Apple standards which are defined on Apple's official site. Despite this, our app was rejected 2-3 times for different reasons.

Why does Apple not give all reasons for an app rejection?
Where can I find more information about the app review process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't give us much to go on, like what the reasons where and such. BUT, when it comes to Apple, a lot has to come down to the App Reviewer and if they had a good day or not. I have had one rejected, and submitted it again, changing a font and color, and it was then successfully accepted into the App Store.
At the end of the day though, they are professionals, and if there is a reason they have given, fix it and move on. It could be something as simple as UI Design ?
You say they have given you 3 different reasons, but then say why are they not giving you all the reason ?? 
[Apple ~ App Review Guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/)

Answer (score 1):

- Watch the video The [Ingredients of Great Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/ios/31/) to understand the basics of great apps.
- Watch the video [iPhone and iPad User Interface Design](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/ios/29/) for practical design tips.
- Watch [iOS Development Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) to learn about programming and design tips.
- Review the iOS [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) and ensure that your app's interface and design adhere to these guidelines.